# Google cloud failing to pull its own image

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to test google cloud kubernetes. 
I created a cluster (all default setting) and pushed my docker image to gc image registry. When in workload I try to deploy the image, it gives me this error:

`Pod errors: ImagePullBackOff`

I tried to search around but all of the problems are related to when you have your docker registry outside google/kubernetes.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you give more details? Full logs, description how you pushing etc. `ImagePullBackOff` is a too general error.

Comment: So basically, I pushed an image to google's private repository following their guide. Then setup a cluster. Tried to deploy in workload and their UI, they could see my image! I selected it and pressed deploy! Then it tells me that it cannot pull the image! Nothing more! ps: I am using their UI

Comment: I more or less understood what you did, but unfortunately I cannot help you without logs. At least result of `kubectl describe pod $pod_name` result. There are no any general problems with UI interface and it's working for me.

Comment: OK, I ran the command and I got this error: `Error from server (Forbidden): pods "cluster-1" is forbidden: User "client" cannot get pods in the namespace "default": Unknown user "client"`

Comment: That means you are not connected to the cluster. Run this command first:
$ `gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-1 --zone ZONE --project PROJECT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tnx for the guides. I found the solution for my problem. It was all about correct permissions for different services. As I messed up (deleted/updated) my services permissions, it failed even to create cluster. I created a new project and compared permissions created there with my current one and found out the missing permissions.

These are the required permissions in order to make a cluster and deploy an image to it:

`service-{projectID}@containerregistry.iam.gserviceaccount.com` -> Editor

`service-{projectID}@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com` -> Editor

`{projectID}@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` -> Editor

`{projectID}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` -> Editor